# Nested Dynamic Component

Tags: angular, typescript

I am learning Angular 2 and i want to build http://filebrowserapp.herokuapp.com/#/ demo in angular 2..

Is it possible to it using Dynamic Component OR is their any other way to achieve this ?? I am trying to use dynamic components but the probem is to how i can change `viewcontainerRef` when user click on folder? so i can append json response to that folder. Can i change `viewcontainerRef` object while i use `createcomponent`?

i want structure like

```
<ul>
  <li>Root1 Folder
    <ul>
      <li>Sub Root1 Folder</li>
      <li>Sub Root2 Folder
     <ul>
   <li>Sub Root Folder</li>
</li>
<li>Root2 Folder</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Seens like this would work with plain old `*ngFor` and the use of a named `<router-outlet>`

Comment: @AluanHaddad but nested list will be added dynamically when i click on root folder